# Moving options from a <select> to a <select multiple> - the option select attribute is breaking?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, prototypejs, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to write a plugin for Prototype where a user clicks on a dropdown and it replaces it with a multi-select element. I am almost finished with it. Everything works great until a user selects what they want displayed, and submits the form to the same page. I am using PHP to keep what the user chose selected using the `selected` attribute of the `<option>` tag. So my plugin runs after that and copies the options to the multi-select, and this is where the problem comes in. Let's say a user chose 3 items, in the html code of the multi-select all 3 items would have the `selected` attribute, but only the last one would be highlighted and when re-submitting the form at that point, it really only submits the highlighted one. [**Here is a demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVqA8/) Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<select id="test1">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option selected="selected">Option 2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="test2" multiple="multiple">
</select>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('test1').childElements().each(function(option){
    $('test2').insert(option);
});
```

​

Comment: don't you need multiple="multiple" on the first select box too?

Comment: @nathanhayfield - Yeah that's the problem. I want it to look like just a normal select box without having to worry with styling or anything like that.

Comment: Well, you cannot have two `selected` options in a simple dropdown. Only one of them will stay selected, the browser normalizes it. At the time your Javascript runs, only one will be selected. I don't think you could do anything about this.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - Right but the HTML code is still there in the multi-select. If you inspect it you will see that it has more than one option selected. So it seems like it should work?

Comment: @Aust The HTML code and the DOM is not the same. You are working with the DOM.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - True. I guess my question is then, how do I manipulate what is selected another way?

Comment: @Aust I don't know prototype, but you could try to read the *attribute* of the `option`, and set the DOM *property* accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first dropdown is not a multiple select, and it can have only one selected item, the DOM will be normalized, only one of the options will have the `selected` property set to `true`.

Seems like when you copy them, the attribute is still there, so you have to read it and set the `selected` property accordingly.

Never used Prototype, but I came up with something like this:

```
$('test1').childElements().each(function(option){
    $('test2').insert(option);
    option.selected = $(option).readAttribute('selected');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVqA8/1/) - tested in Chrome only

Comment: I tested it in Chrome, FF, and IE. It works perfectly. Thanks. :)